# Why is post/create method failing with error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to RoR. Wanted to try if my next web app should be RoR based. Started out following this trail: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html. Worked like a charm in the beginning, but i'm unable to get the darn thing to create new records. Any hint as to what i'm missing is appreciated.

The error i'm getting is this:

```
D, [2020-12-18T09:59:56.917197 #132399] DEBUG -- : Createevent
F, [2020-12-18T09:59:56.917893 #132399] FATAL -- :   
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: Event):
  
app/controllers/event_controller.rb:33:in `event_params'
```

My routing looks like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    post 'event/new', to: 'event#create'
    resources :event 
end
```

(I'm baffled by the need for specifying the POST above, but without it the create is never fired.  ).

The eventcontroller looks like this:

```
class EventController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @events = Event.all
  end

  def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    logger = Rails.logger
    logger.info 'NewEvent'
    @event = Event.new
  end

  def create
    logger = Rails.logger
    logger.debug 'Createevent'

    @event = Event.new(event_params)

    logger.debug 'Eventcreated'

    if @event.save
      redirect_to event_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
    def event_params
      params.require(:Event).permit(:EventName, :Description, :EventStart, :EventEnd, :Maxparticipants, :Waitlist )
    end

end
```

Index and show works fine.

The new.html.erb looks like this:

```
<h1>New Event</h1>

dsfsdfds

<%= form_with model: @Event do |form| %>
  <div>
    <%= form.label :eventname %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :EventName %>
    <%= @event.errors.full_messages_for(:EventName).each do |message| %>
      <div><%= message %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= form.label :Description %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :Description %>
    <%= @event.errors.full_messages_for(:description).each do |message| %>
      <div><%= message %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= form.label :EventStart %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :EventStart %>
    <%= @event.errors.full_messages_for(:eventstart).each do |message| %>
      <div><%= message %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= form.label :Eventend %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :Eventend %>
    <%= @event.errors.full_messages_for(:eventend).each do |message| %>
      <div><%= message %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= form.label :Maxparticipants %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :Maxparticipants %>
    <%= @event.errors.full_messages_for(:Maxparticipants).each do |message| %>
      <div><%= message %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= form.label :Waitlist %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :Waitlist %>
    <%= @event.errors.full_messages_for(:waitlist).each do |message| %>
      <div><%= message %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>

  <%= submit_tag "Create" %>


<% end %>
```

Routes:

```
                              Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
                            event_new POST   /event/new(.:format)                                                                     event#create
                          event_index GET    /event(.:format)                                                                         event#index
                                      POST   /event(.:format)                                                                         event#create
                            new_event GET    /event/new(.:format)                                                                     event#new
                           edit_event GET    /event/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                event#edit
                                event GET    /event/:id(.:format)                                                                     event#show
                                      PATCH  /event/:id(.:format)                                                                     event#update
                                      PUT    /event/:id(.:format)                                                                     event#update
                                      DELETE /event/:id(.:format)                                                                     event#destroy
```

Things created using:

```
bin/rails generate model Event EventName:string Description:string EventStart:datetime EventEnd:datetime Maxparticipants:integer WaitList:integer
bin/rails generate controller Event index
```

Version:

```
About your application's environment
Rails version             6.0.3.4
Ruby version              ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x86_64-linux]
RubyGems version          3.1.4
Rack version              2.2.3
```

Thanks to Hackman & nathanvda for clarifying. I scratched everything and started over and i finally got it working. Still way too much woodo and black magic for my taste though. The error message part got me baffled for three consecutive hours.

As stated i followed the guide and therefore ended up using (in new)

```
<%= form_with model: @event do |form| %>

  <% if @event.errors.any? %>
    <h2>Errors</h2>
    <ul>
      <% @event.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>  
  ...
```

Which works (well, sort of). The record gets saved if ok, the validations rules gets fired

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  validates :eventname, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true, length: { minimum: 20 }
end
```

and if violated no record gets written to the database, but no error messages either. Nil. Nothing. After poking around on the internet i ended up changing to

```
<%= form_for @event do |form| %>
```

and then error reporting works. Only problem with this solution is that the use of form_for is discouraged as it is being rendered obsolete.

Final version ended up being:

```
<%= form_with model: @event, local: true  do |form| %>
```

Which does the trick.

Next step in my evaluation will be the use of natural keys as the use of surrogate keys is not an option for some of the data structures needed in this project. (during my poking around i got the impression that natural keys are some kind of a sore tooth in RoR, but time will show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start out, your resources in the routes should be pluralized. So `resources :event` should be `resources :events`

Also the controller name should be pluralized. So `EventController` would become `EventsController`.

Now the needed routes should work fine and you can get rid of the specified POST in your routes.rb

Now inside your controller you have the event_params method. There it is preferred to downcase/snake_case the names like this:

```rb
  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:event_name #etc)
  end
```

If your column names in DB are EventName etc, I would advice to rename them.

Last thing: In your form you got `@Event` with uppercase while in the controller#new action you defined `@event` with lowercase. Use lowercase everywhere.

Comment: Thanks!, will try during the weekend. Being really worried now, too many "fuzzylogic" rules embedded, as i understand it now. Make one typo "error" and the entire universe collapses. Without a reasonably understandable error message (that i have found so far).

Comment: Thanks!. Finally got it working with som gotchas as described in the case.

Answer (score 0):

So if you had started as follows:

```
bin/rails generate model Event event_name:string description:string event\-start:datetime event_end:datetime max_participants:integer wait_list:integer
bin/rails generate controller events index
```

Then the generated code would work a lot better.

A few tips to clarify:

- in ruby we only write classes with a capital, for variables we use snake case (everything lowercase and words connected with underscores). So by extension when generating a model all attributes should be snake cased
- a controller in general uses the plural form, since it "controls" all the events (not just one).

Comment: Thanks!. Finally got it working with some gotchas as described in the case.